# Gluon Charm TextField NPE

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

When you clear a `TextField` which is initialized with a `floatText` by `textField.setText(null)`, the `floatText` isn't transitioned back to the bottom, and focusing  the `TextField` again causes a NPE.
`setText("")` doesn't cause the NPE, but the `floatText` still stays on top.

```
public class GluonApplication extends MobileApplication {

@Override
public void init() {

    addViewFactory(HOME_VIEW, () ->
    {

        TextField txtFloating = new TextField();
        txtFloating.setFloatText("floating");

        TextField txtNonFloating = new TextField();
        txtNonFloating.setPromptText("non floating");

        Button btnClear = new Button("clear text");
        btnClear.setOnAction(e -> {
            txtFloating.setText(null);
            txtNonFloating.setText(null);
        });

        VBox boxContent = new VBox(20,txtNonFloating, txtFloating, btnClear);
        boxContent.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        View view = new View(boxContent) {

            @Override
            protected void updateAppBar(AppBar appBar) {
                appBar.setTitleText("Home");
            }

        };

        return view;
    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting, I've created an issue.